# filter only the status value from json response

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

In my doInBackground, im getting a json response lik this, `{"LastName":"","UserID":"","Status":"204","FirstName":""}`

I want to compare the value of the `Status`, in my `onPostExcute()`.

in my asynctask i have implimented my onPostExcute like this, but when I debug it goes to exception from myResJson = responseJson.getString("status");

can anyone help me how to change the `onPostExecute` method.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String myResJson;
        try {

            myResJson = responseJson.getString("status");
            String test = myResJson;
            if (test.equals("200")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, LoginActivity.class);
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(contxt,
                        "Registration Error, Email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Status` instead of `status` to access status from JSONObject because key is `Status` :

```
myResJson = responseJson.getString("Status");
```